# My child's all alone

Tags: riddle

> Faster than a bullet speeding
>
> But larger than a train.
>
> You could say that I'm preceding
>
> Over and over again.
>
> I have some siblings, that's for sure
>
> Their names really are well known
>
> I have one child, I must assure,
>
> My child's all alone.

What am I?

Comment: Is 'preceding' spelt correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are:

> The Earth

Faster than a bullet speeding

> 30 Km/s is its translation speed

But larger than a train.

> obviously is

You could say that I'm preceding

> rotating, translating

Over and over again.

> repeatedly

I have some siblings, that's for sure

> Other planets like Mars

Their names really are well known

> Everyone know almost all of them

I have one child, I must assure,

> The moon

My child's all alone.

> Only one natural satellite

Comment: I was about to send the answer when I saw your post!

Comment: Other than earth, some planets have one moon

Comment: yeah but im a planetist (like nationalist) and is my answer heheh answer other planet if you please :D

Comment: No. Just reminder. Good and upvote for your answer.